# using code contracts in visual studio 2010 professional

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Actually in VS2010 professional edition, there was no code contracts. I had installed the standard version of code contracts.

Now in the Visual Studio 2010 > project properties > I get the code contracts tab.

My Question is if i have used the code contracts in my code, do i need to ship my project with any special dll or other thing so that the code contracts work after deployment.

Also, i am not currently planning to purchase the professional edition of code contracts. kindly explain me.

*** Newly Added ***

I would like to know whether using this mechanism will affect the use of Enterprise Library features like Unity & Exception logging. Also will this work for WCF, because if some new C#4.0 features are not supported in WCF.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer all of your questions but I can say that Code Contracts can be used in VS Professional edition but to get build-time checking to work in Visual Studio you will need VS Premium and up from what I understand.

Also if your interested I did put in a [feature request to support Code Contracts in all editions of Visual Studio](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2268646-include-code-contracts-features-in-all-editions-of) and I could use a little help adding some votes to it to get some attention from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently they have the made the static checker available to all editions of Visual Studio in their 1.4.412128.0 release (December 28, 2011).

Check the [release notes](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/releasenotes.aspx) and you can download the latest msi [here.](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/2/A/B2AC27BD-B797-402D-A02D-1263FBA157FA/Contracts.devlab9ts.msi)

-Hope this helps